# Laravel: How I can get top products from my orders?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get the products that are ordered most often. I can get orders with ordered products this way:

```
$business->orders()->with('products')->get();
```

It returns the next collection (I just show you one order):

```
[
    {
        "id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
        "business_id": "8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77",
        "user_id": null,
        "business_customer_id": null,
        "customer_name": " Alona",
        "customer_email": "alona@fff.ff",
        "customer_phone_number": "123123",
        "customer_street": "#16-31, 5A LORONG HOW SUN,  Bartley Residences, SINGAPORE 536563",
        "customer_city": "Singapore",
        "customer_state": "Singapore",
        "customer_postal_code": "536563",
        "customer_country": "sg",
        "customer_pickup": 0,
        "channel": "store_checkout",
        "currency": "sgd",
        "automatic_discount_name": "amount discount",
        "automatic_discount_amount": 500,
        "line_item_price": 3000,
        "line_item_discount_amount": 0,
        "line_item_tax_amount": 0,
        "automatic_discount_reason": null,
        "additional_discount_amount": 0,
        "business_shipping_id": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
        "shipping_method": "Shipping Not Applicable",
        "shipping_amount": 0,
        "shipping_tax_name": null,
        "shipping_tax_rate": "0.0000",
        "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "slot_date": null,
        "slot_time": null,
        "amount": 2500,
        "coupon_amount": 0,
        "tax_setting_id": null,
        "reference": null,
        "messages": null,
        "remark": null,
        "status": "requires_business_action",
        "executor_id": null,
        "request_ip_address": "116.86.78.44",
        "request_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15",
        "request_method": "post",
        "request_url": "",
        "request_country": null,
        "request_data": {
            "device": {
                "name": "Macintosh",
                "type": "computer"
            },
            "browser": {
                "name": "Safari",
                "version": "14.1.1"
            },
            "platform": {
                "name": "OS X",
                "version": "10_15_7"
            },
            "referrer": "",
            "requests": {
                "email": "alona@fd.com",
                "discount": {
                    "name": "amount discount",
                    "amount": 500
                },
                "shipping": {
                    "option": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
                    "address": {
                        "city": "Singapore",
                        "state": "Singapore",
                        "street": "#16-31, 5A LORONG HOW SUN,  Bartley Residences, SINGAPORE 536563",
                        "country": "sg",
                        "postal_code": "536563"
                    }
                },
                "last_name": "alona",
                "phone_number": "123123"
            }
        },
        "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:50:07",
        "expires_at": null,
        "closed_at": null,
        "products_count": 2,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "94567311-e669-4943-b90e-537669099bc2",
                "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
                "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Black Tote Bag",
                "description": "Small",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Size",
                "variation_value_1": "Small",
                "variation_key_2": null,
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 1500,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 1500,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
                "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": "94567311-e6bb-48b4-8bdf-ad282dcc6d72",
                "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
                "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-7781-4d9a-859e-8296669a9926",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Black Tote Bag",
                "description": "Medium",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Size",
                "variation_value_1": "Medium",
                "variation_key_2": null,
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 1500,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 1500,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
                "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ]
    },
....
]
```

Each order can have multiple products. So I need somehow to get a count of how many times each product was ordered. Something like this:

```
[
   'count' => 37
   'product' => {
                "id": "94567311-e669-4943-b90e-537669099bc2",
                "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
                "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Black Tote Bag",
                "description": "Small",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Size",
                "variation_value_1": "Small",
                "variation_key_2": null,
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 1500,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 1500,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
                "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "deleted_at": null
            },
]
```

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks all!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can count a relation, so assuming you also defined the relation on products. This should be a good start:

```
Products::withCount('orders')->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$business->orders()->with(['products'=>function($qu)
    {
        $qu->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc');
        
    }])->get();
```

Try This